# I can't understand this code. 2 bits number for switching a motor speed and direction on Arduino

Tags: arduino, byte

Can you guys help me understanding this code?

```cpp
#define pin1 2 // motor #1 +
#define pin2 3 // motor #1 –
#define pw1 9 // motor #1 pwm
#define pin3 4 // motor #2 +
#define pin4 5 // motor #2 –
#define pw2 6 // motor #2 pwm

void setup() {
  pinMode(pin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pw1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pw2, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  digitalWrite(pin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(pin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(pin3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(pin4, LOW);
  analogWrite(pw1, 50);
  analogWrite(pw2, 50);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() >= 2) {
    unsigned int a = Serial.read();
    unsigned int b = Serial.read();
    unsigned int val = (b * 256) + a;// THIS
    if (val == 100) {
      // motor 1 reverse
      digitalWrite(pin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(pin2, HIGH);
    } else if (val == 200) {
      // motor #1 stop
      digitalWrite(pin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(pin2, LOW);
    } else if (val == 300) {
      // motor #1 forward
      digitalWrite(pin1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(pin2, LOW);
    } else if (val == 400) {
      // motor #2 reverse
      digitalWrite(pin3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(pin4, HIGH);
    } else if (val == 500) {
      // motor #2 stop
      digitalWrite(pin3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(pin4, LOW);
    } else if (val == 600) {
      // motor #2 forward
      digitalWrite(pin3, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(pin4, LOW);
    } else if (val >= 1000 && val <= 1255) {
      analogWrite (pw1, val – 1000);
    } else if (val >= 2000 && val <= 2255) {
      analogWrite (pw2, val – 2000);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using 2 bytes to control the motors. The serial port is receiving 2 bytes. I need help  with understanding this part of the code:

```cpp
unsigned int a = Serial.read();
unsigned int b = Serial.read();
unsigned int val = (b * 256) + a
```

I just don't see what's happening. This is what I understand: if the serial reads, for example, 1000, it is saved in 2 variables: a= 1000 b= 1000. Then 1000 * 256 = 256000 , then 256000 + 1000 = 257000. But it cannot be, because it will never enter in the last 2 else if... So I figured that I'm failing to understand that part.

And it works. I made the circuit and send those 2 bytes to the serial port and the motor works.

Comment: Serial input is byte-oriented. My guess is that Serial.read returns integer in 0-255 range. So, a is LSB (less-significant byte), casted to integer, and b is MSB (most significant byte). To get val=1000: a = 232, b = 3.

Answer (score 0):

The code will whait untill 2 bytes are set on **serial**.

Serial.read() will take care of each **byte**.

So  `a` will be the first byte introduced, and `b` will be the second one.

[I suggest to check this arduino reference](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read)

Comment: ok, but then, what exactly the funtion Val makes, this still i dont get

Comment: I supose it's just to scale those numbers `a` `b`. You could run the program without `val` by modifying all those conditions